# How get navigationBar.titleTextAttributes? works in Swift 4.0?

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4

I used to have NSForegroundColorAttributeName in swift 3 and it works fine for setter and getting the titleColor for UINavigationBar, after upgrading to Swift 4 I could not able to get the value of navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?["NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor"] as? UIColor. Below is the code I am using. Please help...

```
@IBInspectable var titleColor: UIColor? {
    set {
      guard let color = newValue else { return }
      navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: color]
    }
    get {
      return navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?["NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor"] as? UIColor
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the  NSAttributedStringKey `.foregroundColor` instead of a string to your getter:

```
@IBInspectable var titleColor: UIColor? {
    set {
      guard let color = newValue else { return }
      navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: color]
    }
    get {
      return navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?[.foregroundColor] as? UIColor
    }
}
```